# Azure App Service (Linux), NEXT JS app , PM2 not possible to set cluster mode

Tags: azure-web-app-service, next.js, pm2

I have tried to set up a cluster by PM2 on Next JS app on Azure App Service (Linux) using startup command  "pm2-runtime start ecosystem.config.js" or "pm2 --no-daemon start ecosystem.config.js". Both commands fail. When I am using pm2-runtime the current working directory passed to NodeJS script becomes: "wwwroot/ecosystem.config.js/.next" as a "directory parameters" and the server fails. In second command pm2 --no-daemon I receive information Unknown or unexpected option: --no-daemon. Both commands work for "fork" mode. Is it possible to set up a cluster mode for the azure app service with nextjs app?

ecosystem.config.code

```
module.exports = {
    apps: [
        {
            name: 'next',
            script: './node_modules/next/dist/bin/next',
            args: 'start -p ' + (process.env.PORT || 3000), 
            instances: 2,
            exec_mode: 'cluster',
            watch: false,
            autorestart: true,
        },
    ],
};*
```

Errors for --no-daemon

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvXEs.png)

```
Error for pm2-runtime
 Error: Could not find a production build in the '/home/site/wwwroot/ecosystem.config.js/.next' directory. Try building your app with 'next build' before starting the production se
rver. https://err.sh/vercel/next.js/production-start-no-build-id
0|next|     at Server.readBuildId (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/next/next-server/server/next-server.ts:2044:15)
0|next|     |     at new Server (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/next/next-server/server/next-server.ts:199:25)
0|next|     |     at createServer (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/next/server/next.ts:41:10)
0|next|     |     at start (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/next/server/lib/start-server.ts:9:15)
0|next|     |     at exec (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/next/cli/next-start.ts:53:3)
0|next|     |     at /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/next/bin/next.ts:113:19 code here
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding command pm2 list before pm2-runtime solves the issue, I suppose that the command pm2 list initializes the pm2 and sets the proper path for pm2-runtime.

Comment: Thank you! I was stuck on this for ages!

Comment: You sir, are the hero we don't deserve :-O  I've been stuck on this specific issue for months

Comment: Saved me as well. Thank you! To be clear for others, you will need `pm2 list && pm2 ...`.